Docker compose up and down issue when dealing with multiple forks of a repo
Lets say I have a original project locally at /path/to/org/project which uses docker compose.
I also have its fork at /path/to/user/project. Both are in same state.
I start Docker containers in original project:
user@host:/path/to/org/project$ docker compose up -d

Now in fork when I try to run:
user@host:/path/to/user/project$ docker compose down --remove-orphans

it removes container created by original repo.
Why so?

Compose associates containers with a project name which by default is the basename of the current directory; in your example both have the same name project.  Rename one of the directories, or set a COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable in one directory or the other, or (consistently) use a docker compose -p option.
